# c++ use template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I hava a project in c++ course.
is it possible?

```
#include<iostream>
#include "mylist.hpp"

int main(){
    mylist<int> *x = new mylist<int>(); //I know this is possible.
    mylist *y = new mylist(); //....how?
}
```

mylist.hpp is header file contains about mylist class.
Is there any way to compile this code such as inheritance, overload...?

Comment: You are essentially asking "please give me a glass of". No, please specify whether you want beer or water!

Comment: I hava a project in c++ course. is it possible? You tell me.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Agreed. I think it is just as possible/useful as asking someone to help you write code to sort colored socks alphabetically by smell.

Comment: @callyalater, nice allegory.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb OK. I will be careful about that at next time.

Comment: If you try to compile it you'll know if what you have written is possible (well, at least 'syntactically correct')...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to compile this code such as inheritance, overload...?

No. Not as you are trying to at least.

```
mylist *y = new mylist(); //....how?
```

isn't valid since you have to provide a template parameter for `mylist` like `mylist<MyType>`.

You're probably looking for *template specializations*.

Comment: T.A provided this code to me "this is test case!!!"
and i got so many errors..

Comment: @seunghwanJeong Well, kick T.A. in the ass :-P ...

Comment: Preferrably so hard that T.A. is launched off-campus, never to find the way back. No kidding.

Comment: @SergeyA Sure, there seem to be loads of incompetent T.A.'s nowadays.

Comment: Could OP use a template specialization for `mylist<>` and create a using template alias for it?

Comment: @callyalater Not sure if such is possible using the `mylist` symbol as a type alias for that case.